# How to get color of hovered slice in amcharts?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I am currently using amcharts in my project. I have overridden the default tooltip using

`pieSeries.slices.template.tooltipHTML = //MY HTML HERE FOR THE TOOLTIP`

In the HTML,  I want the background color same as the slice color that is hovered. I have gone through the documentation but could not find anything. What I was thinking is maybe if I can get the hover event, then if I get the color or index of currently hovered slice(assuming that I can get the color of the slice from its instance), I can set the color of my HTML Element via Javascript. But I don't know, maybe there is a straight forward way to achieve this as this is not a rare requirement. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you using theme colours, or manually setting colours for each entry in the data series?

Comment: I can go with either, whatever is the best approach for the problem. I tried setting custom colors, but in my tooltip HTML, I could not find a way to set color for each slice. Iam using amcharts first time, what all variables I have access to in HTML other than category and value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that amCharts sets the same colour for the tooltip by default, even when custom tooltip HTML is being set:

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 *
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 *
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "Lithuania",
  "litres": 501.9,
  "color": am4core.color("#ED1C24")
}, {
  "country": "Czechia",
  "litres": 301.9,
  "color": am4core.color("#235789")
}, {
  "country": "Ireland",
  "litres": 201.1,
  "color": am4core.color("#F1D302")
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "litres": 165.8,
  "color": am4core.color("#020100")
}];

// Add and configure Series
var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "litres";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "country";
pieSeries.slices.template.propertyFields.fill = "color";
pieSeries.slices.template.tooltipHTML = "<p>My custom tooltip color:  {color}</p>"

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

(example based on [this amCharts demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/ZEzNEWe))

This holds true whether using the custom colours, or theme colours by removing this line:

```js
pieSeries.slices.template.propertyFields.fill = "color";
```

So maybe this property is being overridden elsewhere in your code. You can force the tooltip to have the same fill colour by adding this line ([more details here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/tooltips/#Fill)):

```js
chart.tooltip.getFillFromObject = true;
```

EDIT: The colour can also be accessed in the tooltip HTML via `"{color}"`, so that it could be used in a style attribute, for example.

Comment: Though my case was slightly different as the HTML contained a table and I need to get the color to style specific part of the table but you pointed in the right direction. Added color property in chart data and could access in the tooltip HTML via {color}

Comment: Nice! I'm glad it worked out. For completeness, I've added the part about `"{color}"` to this answer as well.